# Routes/Pylons Fails Before Touching My Code

Tags: python, regex, routes, pylons, mod-wsgi

I am very puzzled over this error.  In a previously functional Pylons app (running on apache/mod_wsgi), Routes has exploded.  When I attempt to access my application, no matter what URL I use, I get the Apache "Internal server error" page and the following traceback in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

```
[Sat Oct 02 2010] WSGI Variables
[Sat Oct 02 2010] --------------
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   application: <beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware object at 0xb885be6c>
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   beaker.get_session: <bound method SessionMiddleware._get_session of <beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware object at 0xb885be6c>>
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   beaker.session: {'_accessed_time': 1286040208.138742, '_creation_time': 1286040208.138742}
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.application_group: '192.168.1.51|'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.callable_object: 'application'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.handler_script: ''
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.input_chunked: '0'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.listener_host: ''
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.listener_port: '80'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.process_group: ''
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.request_handler: 'wsgi-script'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.script_reloading: '1'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   mod_wsgi.version: (3, 3)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   paste.registry: <paste.registry.Registry object at 0xb7e373ac>
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   paste.throw_errors: True
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   wsgi process: 'Multi process AND threads (?)'
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   wsgi.file_wrapper: <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0xb70c77b8>
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   wsgi.version: (1, 1)
[Sat Oct 02 2010] [client 192.168.1.50]
------------------------------------------------------------
[Sat Oct 02 2010] mod_wsgi (pid=13389): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/pylons/myapp/myapp.wsgi'.
[Sat Oct 02 2010] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Paste-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/paste/cascade.py", line 130, in __call__
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     return self.apps[-1](environ, start_response)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Paste-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/paste/registry.py", line 375, in __call__
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     app_iter = self.application(environ, start_response)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg/pylons/middleware.py", line 163, in __call__
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     self.app, new_environ, catch_exc_info=True)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pylons-1.0-py2.7.egg/pylons/util.py", line 48, in call_wsgi_application
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     app_iter = application(environ, start_response)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WebError-0.10.2-py2.7.egg/weberror/errormiddleware.py", line 156, in __call__
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     return self.application(environ, start_response)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/beaker/middleware.py", line 152, in __call__
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg/routes/middleware.py", line 84, in __call__
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     results = self.mapper.routematch(environ=environ)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg/routes/mapper.py", line 690, in routematch
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     result = self._match(url, environ)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg/routes/mapper.py", line 609, in _match
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     self.create_regs()
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg/routes/mapper.py", line 560, in create_regs
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     self._create_regs(*args, **kwargs)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg/routes/mapper.py", line 578, in _create_regs
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     route.makeregexp(clist)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Routes-1.12.3-py2.7.egg/routes/route.py", line 306, in makeregexp
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     self.regmatch = re.compile(reg)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     return _compile(pattern, flags)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 243, in _compile
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 500, in compile
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 673, in parse
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 308, in _parse_sub
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 544, in _parse
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     if not isname(name):
[Sat Oct 02 2010]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 218, in isname
[Sat Oct 02 2010]     if not isident(name[0]):
[Sat Oct 02 2010] IndexError: string index out of range
```

This has me very confused because it appears that Routes falls over and dies **before it ever touches my code!**  The only thing it touches is my myapp.wsgi file; neither myapp.wsgi nor my development.ini files have changed between the last working state of the app and now, only model/controller/template files.  I have not updated any packages between the last working state of the app and now.  The files that I have changed in my app are controller, model, and template files - none of which appear in the traceback.  I thought that I might have changed routing.py without remembering it, and the traceback leads to the regular expression processing modules, so I went into routing.py and commented out all lines that use Routes' [requirements feature](http://routes.groovie.org/manual.html#requirements) - no change, same error.  Retried with lots of `apache2ctl restart` - no change, same error.

What in blue blazes is going on here, and what *in my app* might have caused it?

**Solution:**
The culprit was an innocent-looking route -

`map.redirect('/foo/*', '/', _redirect_code='301 Moved Permanently')`.

It looks like that bare asterisk made Routes throw a wobbly.  I corrected it by making the match route into `'/foo/{bar}'` and then dropping the value of bar on the floor.  I'm still puzzled about why Routes suffered a meltdown over that instead of being able to throw something like a SyntaxError, but hey, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look in your app's `config/routing.py` file, and add some debugging steps there, or try editing or removing some of the map.connect(...) calls. If you comment out each controller's mapping one at a time, you might be able to narrow down one controller's mapping that is causing this.

Comment: Right: divide and conquer time!

Comment: That led to the solution.  Thanks.